# I cant figure out this array

Tags: java, arrays

Im doing some personal work, and I am using this array that I thought of, but I cant figure out whats the array is after the code stops running.

```
int cnt = 0; 
int[][] numarray = new int[2][3]; 
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j< 2; j++) {
    numarray[j][i] = cnt; 
    cnt++; 
  }
}
```

I am pretty sure that it ends at [2][1] but I am not 100% sure of it

Comment: Try using a debugger to step through the code and see for yourself.

Comment: or even insert some `println` statements

Comment: I tried to use the println but it wasnt working and I think its right, but the cnt is whats confusing me

Comment: Do you want to know about cnt or in your code has any defect which you want to figure out ?

Answer (score 1):

Just tried this code:

```
    int cnt = 0; 
    int[][] numarray = new int[2][3]; 
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j< 2; j++) {
        numarray[j][i] = cnt; 
        cnt++; 
        System.out.print(numarray[j][i]+" ");
      }
      System.out.println("");
    }
```

and got this result:

```
0 1 
2 3 
4 5
```

The 'cnt' is incremented by 1 for each iteration. That's why you have 0,1,2,3,4,5.

Also learn how to use debugger in an IDE, you can then explore the value of i, j, cnt by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try this?

```
    int cnt = 0; 
    int[][] numarray = new int[2][3]; 
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j< 2; j++) {
        numarray[j][i] = cnt;
        System.out.println(String.format("array[%d[%d]=%d",j,i,numarray[j][i]));
        cnt++; 
      }
    }
```

Comment: do you understand whats happeneing to the cnt?

Comment: cnt++ means cnt = cnt + 1;

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate the array after code finish

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j< 3; j++) {
        System.out.print(numarray[i][j]+" ");
      }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

summary: `cnt` is incremented by `1` for each iteration in the inner for loop.

`cnt` is being incremented by 1 i.e. `cnt++` is same as `cnt = cnt + 1;`
so count values increment from 0 i.e. 0,1,2,3,4,5... Also note, the value of `cnt` is assigned to the array being created, where you have `numarray[j][i] = cnt;`

You can simply printout the value using `System.out.println(cnt);`